# "Habere" VS dative and genitive of possession?

Tags: grammar-choice, genitive, dative

To mean something that is not owned legally, not owned with the meaning of "being the owner", like when I say "We have a pope", could I use "habere" or only the dative or genitive of possession?

Is the meaning the same between those 2 structures? When to use the one and when to use the other one?

With something I really own, unlike the pope, but like a dog or a house, is this different?

Doesn't "habere" mean to own, with the meaning of "to be the master"?

Answer (score 4):

This answer only considers the nuances of *habere*, not a comparison between it and the possessive dative.
The possessive genitive is different; it functions mostly like the English genitive and is used to express things like "my dog" rather than "I have a dog".

The example of the pope actually makes a good example for *habere*.
The [canonical announcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habemus_papam) upon the selection of a new pope begins:

> *Annuntio vobis gaudium magnum: habemus Papam.*

We have a pope, but we do not own him or rule him in any reasonable sense.
One could try to argue that this is post-classical, but no.

Please take a look at [the entry for *habere* in Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=habeo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for a classical view.
It has a wide variety of uses, including clear ownership (having money) and clear lack thereof (having a brother).

The verb *habere* is very broad, and only rarely does it have the nuance of "to be the master [of]".
Assigning this meaning to it in general is not justified at all.

Comment: It's already very interesting.

Comment: It was exactly why I asked this question, a Latin teacher told me it was post-classical, but I had some doubts.

Comment: @Quidam It's always good to doubt your teacher, be it Latin or otherwise. (But don't be too vocal about your doubts in front of them!)

Comment: I am my own teacher, I teach myself latin using the internet and books (I didn't have the chance to attend Latin classes at school), but I debate a lot about Latin words, in order to learn. Anyway, I'm a bit a St Thomas, if someone tells me it's the rule, I need to see this rule.